# How can I use async/await statements in nested functions?

Tags: javascript

There is a nested function where asnyc functions and normal functions are used. I am a beginner in JavaScript by the way.

```
async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async context => {
      document.getElementById("status").value = "";
      let checks = [];
      const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const uR = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
      uR.load('values');
      await context.sync();
      let data2 =uR.values;
      let data2.forEach((row,index)=>{
      docfunction(row);
```

Within this `docfunction` I want to use:

```
   function docfunction(row) {
    let checknumber = context.workbook.functions.isNumber(row[5]);
    checknumber.load('value');
    await context.sync();
    checknumber = checknumber.value;
```

However, `await context.sync()` is not working.

Comment: Can you add some more code as snippet.

Comment: I guess you must declare `docfunction` as async too, `async function docfunction(row) {...}`. So, when invoking that function use `await docfunction(row)`;
One more thing, bear in mind context.sync() should be async (promise)! But, as the own function name suggests, `context.sync()` looks *sync*, so, just remove await from this line.

Comment: Explain in more detail what you mean by "not working".  context.sync returns a Promise and await should work as microsoft's docs show as example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern  it is also recommended that you do not use sync in a loop

Comment: let data2.forEach is also invalid syntax.  are you just having trouble treating the data2 looping as async?

Comment: thank you very much for the comments: syntax is fixed -  i still get the error messsage: uncaught (in promise) richapi.error: before reading the property value, call the load method on the containing object. I need to say that docfunction has now the variables row and context.

Comment: And probably you'll need to [avoid `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Comment: the trouble is within the function docfunction(row,context). Here  the error message appears in the line checknumber = checknumber.value after the await context.sync();

Comment: add console.log of those values or use the debugger and make sure it is actually those places throwing the error.  console.log(checknumber.toJSON()) (this will attempt to output all properties and show `.load` msgs for elements not properly loaded) to see if it's really `checknumber` that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to make the `docfunction` async in order to make it work:

```
async function docfunction(row) {
let checknumber = context.workbook.functions.isNumber(row[5]);
checknumber.load('value');
await context.sync();
checknumber = checknumber.value;
```

then you need to call it with `await` keyword inside your `run` function:

```
await dysfunction(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served returning a list of Promises and using a `for await of` loop, but this should be what you are looking for.
You could make it work with a `.forEach`, but there is really no reason to as it does not make the code any more readable.

```
async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async context => {
      document.getElementById("status").value = "";
      let checks = [];
      const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const uR = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
      uR.load('values');
      await context.sync();
      let data2 =uR.values;
      for(const [row,index] of data2.entries()) {
        await docfunction(row);
```

...

```
   async function docfunction(row) {
    let checknumber = context.workbook.functions.isNumber(row[5]);
    checknumber.load('value');
    await context.sync();
    checknumber = checknumber.value;
```

Answer (score -1):

> await expect a promise, Here is dummy code for async/await.

```
async function run() {
    // It will wait for the promise to resolve
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(console.log('Inside promise'));
        }, 3000);
    });
    // when promise gets resolved it will print
    console.log('Outside Promise');
}

run();
```